# fatal error: TXMLNode.h: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, path, installation-package

I want install package [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) on my computer, It should be done with command `./configure && make && make install`, at the step of `make`, I met an error:

```
In file included from /home/wm/root-6.10.02/hist/unfold/src/TUnfoldBinningXML.cxx:123:0:
include/TUnfoldBinningXML.h:47:22: fatal error: TXMLNode.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:723: recipe for target 'hist/unfold/src/TUnfoldBinningXML.o' failed
make: *** [hist/unfold/src/TUnfoldBinningXML.o] Error 1
```

my OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Then I check for `config.log`

```
  98    Checking for libXpm ...
  99    libraries to check for:  libXpm.so libXpm.sl libXpm.tbd libXpm.dylib libXpm.dll.a  libXpm.a libXpm.lib libXpm
 100   Checking in directories /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib for  libXpm.so libXpm.sl libXpm.tbd libXpm.     dylib libXpm.dll.a  libXpm.a libXpm.lib libXpm
 101   Checking for library libXpm.so in directory /usr/local/lib
 102    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.so
 103   libXpm.so not found in /usr/local/lib
 104   Checking for library libXpm.sl in directory /usr/local/lib
 105    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.sl
 106   libXpm.sl not found in /usr/local/lib
 107   Checking for library libXpm.tbd in directory /usr/local/lib
 108    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.tbd
 109   libXpm.tbd not found in /usr/local/lib
 110   Checking for library libXpm.dylib in directory /usr/local/lib
 111    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.dylib
 112   libXpm.dylib not found in /usr/local/lib
 113   Checking for library libXpm.dll.a in directory /usr/local/lib
 114    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.dll.a
 115   libXpm.dll.a not found in /usr/local/lib
 116   Checking for library libXpm.a in directory /usr/local/lib
 117    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.a
 118   libXpm.a not found in /usr/local/lib
 119   Checking for library libXpm.lib in directory /usr/local/lib
 120    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm.lib
 121   libXpm.lib not found in /usr/local/lib
 122   Checking for library libXpm in directory /usr/local/lib
 123    Checking /usr/local/lib/libXpm
 124   libXpm not found in /usr/local/lib
 125  Checking in directories /usr/lib64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64 /usr/lib for  libXpm.so libXpm.sl libXpm.tbd libXpm.dylib libXpm.dll.a  libX     pm.a libXpm.lib libXpm
 126   Checking for library libXpm.so in directory /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 127    Checking /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so
 128    Found file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so
 129 Checking if /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so is a 64-bit library
 130  file -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so | grep '64-bit'
 131  result: 1
 132  is a 64bit library
```

and several mistakes like this. I think that I have installed for example `libxpm-dev`

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxpm-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxpm-dev is already the newest version (1:3.5.11-1ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 321 not upgraded.
```

but there is no output of `ldconfig -p | grep libxpm-dev`, 
the output of `locate libxpm-dev` is

```
/usr/share/doc/libxpm-dev
/usr/share/doc/libxpm-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxpm-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libxpm-dev/xpm.PS.gz
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libxpm-dev
/var/cache/apt/archives/libxpm-dev_1%3a3.5.11-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxpm-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxpm-dev:amd64.md5sums
```

Then I try :

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/doc
$ ~/root-6.10.02$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/cache/apt/archives
$ ~/root-6.10.02$ export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/dpkg/info
```

still doesn't work.

so what to do now?

Comment: TXMLNode.h is part of ROOT. If it can't be found then either you don't have the full source tree or the build process is broken.

Comment: I'm hitting the exact same problem (TXMLNode.h not being found) when building ROOT 6.10.04 from source...

Comment: @KennethHoste [The "configure" script is known to be broken in ROOT 6.
Use the CMake based building method](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/error-fatal-error-txmlnode-h-no-such-file-or-directory-i-met-while-installing-root/25933/2)

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Indeed, that seemed to be the issue. I've updated our build scripts to use CMake for ROOT from now on, seems to be going smoothly. Thanks for the feedback!